# How Can I set a VPN using winHttp?

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing an windows app that down load some image from google's service.
I use the WinHttp for Http connection.
However the Google is blocked in my area.
Is it possible to connect to a VPN server during the codes of WinHttp connection and request?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the WinInet or WinHTTP APIs for establishing a VPN connection.  You can use [`RasDial()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004.aspx) to establish a VPN connection before then sending your HTTP request.  See MSDN's documentation for more details:

[Virtual Private Network Connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382345.aspx)

> The Remote Access Service (RAS) supports Virtual Private Network (VPN) connections in addition to conventional remote access connections that use Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP). In a VPN connection, the VPN packets are encapsulated in IP packets and sent across an IP network such as the Internet. Therefore, access to an IP network is a requirement in order to establish a VPN connection. If the client computer has an always-on connection to an IP network, for example a connection to an IP LAN, the client can establish the VPN connection using a single call to the [RasDial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004.aspx) function.
>
> If the client computer does not have an always-on connection to an IP network, two calls to [RasDial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004.aspx) are required to establish the VPN connection. The first call establishes a dial-up connection to the IP network; the second call establishes the VPN connection.